# Event contextmenu is not trigger on Safari with Leaflet and Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant

Tags: javascript, google-maps, safari, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

Right click don't work on Safari (desktop) with googleMutant layer for Leaflet. On the jsfiddle bellow, contextmenu event is trigger on Open street map but not on google map. However it work fine on other browsers.

```
leafletData.getMap("map").then(function(map){

    for (var k in mapEvents) {
        var eventName = mapEvents[k];
        map.on(eventName, function(event){
            $scope.eventDetected = event.type;
        });
    }

    var roadMutant = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
        maxZoom: 24,
        type:'roadmap'
    });

    var satMutant = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
        maxZoom: 24,
        type:'satellite'
    });

    var osm = L.gridLayer("//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        subdomains : [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
        attribution: "&copy; <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\">OpenStreetMap</a>",
        continuousWorld : false,
        unloadInvisibleTiles : false,
        updateWhenIdle : true,
        zoomOffset : 0,
        maxZoom: 20
    }).addTo(map);

    L.control.layers({
        Roadmap: roadMutant,
        Aerial: satMutant,
        StreetMap: osm
    }, {}, {
            collapsed: false
    }).addTo(map);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/romsdev/hvj22kLu/

I tried some fix with z-index and pointer-event like describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386814/leaflet-map-issue-in-safari-using-iphone-and-ipad) or [here](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant/issues/42) but nothing work for desktop version.